# Migrations in separate assembly how to avoid hardcoded connection string?

Tags: asp.net-core, database-migration, entity-framework-core, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm writing ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core application and I want to store my data access layer in separate assembly, so I followed this tutorial: http://www.michael-whelan.net/ef-core-101-migrations-in-separate-assembly/

But I would also like to avoid hardcoding connection string. I tried to store it in JSON config file or as environment variable and get it using `ConfigurationBuilder` but when using command line migration tool `dotnet ef migrations` none of these are available.
Is there any way to solve this problem? I'm using 1.0.1 versions of both .NET Core and EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue I create a class library only for migration with a DbContext deriving from my DbContext but with hard connected connection string.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ChatLe.Repository.Identity.SqlServer
{
    public class ChatLeIdentityDbContext: ChatLe.Models.ChatLeIdentityDbContext
    {
        public ChatLeIdentityDbContext()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=chatle;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I launch ef tool command like this :

- To add a migration run `dotnet ef --startup-project {path to my startup project} migrations add login-activity --context ChatLe.Repository.Identity.SqlServer.ChatLeIdentityDbContext`
- To upgrade the database run `dotnet ef --startup-project {path to my startup project} database update --context ChatLe.Repository.Identity.SqlServer.ChatLeIdentityDbContext`

Read the full sample on  my git hub project : https://github.com/aguacongas/chatle/tree/develop/src/ChatLe.Repository.Identity.SqlServer

Comment: It's the same as in the tutorial I followed but there `IDbContextFactory<>` is used instead of deriving context. It still does not resolve the problem with hardcoding connection string.

Comment: I agree but this specific assembly is used only for dev to generate migration, not in your production environment and it's not referenced by your application.